# Insert Into combination of SELECT FROM and regular value

Tags: mysql, select, syntax, insert

How can I insert into from another table in Mysql and include a normal value as well?

E.g.

`INSERT INTO history (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (SELECT t_col1 FROM tabl2, 5, 76)`

The above statement returns an error.

Comment: What is `5` and `76` supposed to be? Are those values within `tabl2` you wish to grab or arbitrary values you wish to insert into `history`?

Comment: values 5 and 76 are random values - it can also be "test" or similar - and they are not in the tabl2

Comment: If they are columns or values you wish to return out of your sub query, move the values to your `SELECT` clause and not in the `FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO history(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT t_col1, 5, 76
    FROM tabl2;
```

The `values` keyword is not needed.  Actually, `insert . . . select` does everything that `insert . . . values` does, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using values(inner query) you can simply write inner query and it shall work fine